# OpenLiberty caching feature

Tags: caching, infinispan, open-liberty, jcache

I would like to add some caching features to my JEE application running on OpenLiberty.
I would rely on JCache API and Infinispan.

I understand that some OpenLiberty features could use some caching capabilities relying on this stack ([session caching for example](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/distributed-session-caching.html)) but I just want to be able to manage my own cache to store my own datas.

I'm wondering if there is a way to enable the use of ['cache', 'cacheManager' and 'cachingProvider'](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/distributed-caching-jcache.html) configuration elements without enabling a feature that I don't need.
I would expect a "cache" feature but it seems that it is always triggered by an other feature and cannot be enabled independently.
Do I miss something ?

My last option will be to use Infinispan and JCache independently without relying on OpenLiberty cache configuration capabilities.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Liberty doesn't have a JCache feature for you to use natively.  You will need to provide the JCache APIs and infinispan libraries in your application or in a library stanza in your server.xml that your applications references.